# Initramfs suddenly speaks IPv6 but no SSH login

Tags: ssh, security, startup, initramfs, ipv6

I have been running a configuration with an encrypted root partition and network unlock via Dropbear in initramfs for some time on my Utopic Xubuntu Mediacenter. Since I am actively using IPv6 to access devices in the network from outside, it has always been a pity that initramfs-tools didn't support IPv6.

Now, without me knowing of any major update, the machine is suddenly reachable via IPv6 before the root partition is accessible, BUT neither my rsa key from /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/authorized_keys nor my password as a user are accepted (latter makes sense of course, since /etc/shadow is not decrypted yet).

dmesg says NOTHING about what's going on, this is all that is logged from boot, over two unsuccessful login attempts via ssh until decryption locally on the keyboard:

```
[    3.059032] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2010 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0007/0003:046D:C52B.0009/input/input9
[    3.059179] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0009: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:2010] on usb-0000:00:12.0-4:2
[    3.225536] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    3.910848] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[    3.910871] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[    3.910920] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.458419] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link up
[    6.458436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   46.401849] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   66.931909] raid6: sse2x1    3291 MB/s
[   66.999840] raid6: sse2x2    3691 MB/s
[   67.067780] raid6: sse2x4    4607 MB/s
[   67.067782] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 (4607 MB/s)
[   67.067784] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[   67.069904] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
[   67.107736]    avx       :  6114.000 MB/sec
[   67.130684] Btrfs loaded
[   67.151180] BTRFS: device fsid 47b1efee-d626-41dc-97e3-07205d612763 devid 1 transid 222612 /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
[   67.158124] BTRFS info (device dm-0): disk space caching is enabled
[   67.199031] BTRFS: detected SSD devices, enabling SSD mode
[   67.369117] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (339) killed by TERM signal
```

Can anybody tell my what is going on here?

- Why is IPv6 suddenly possible, though there was no major update and it is documented everywhere that it is not supported yet?
- How do I get authentication running again?
- Where can I find additional logs?
- Should I maybe even worry that there is some strange new network capability with unknown functionality?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: I am aware of the nature of Stack Exchange, and in my opinion, it doesn't make sense to split up this question. While there are technical four questions in the end, they deal with one problem and are more a mean of hinting how to approach the answer or allow me to supply more information. Each of the for bullet points would require to post the description before and each of those Q&A requests would eventually lead to the same final answer, as I am pretty sure there is just one problem.

Comment: I assume you previously accessed dropbear over IPv4. Does that still work the way it used to, or has IPv4 behavior also changed?